# Zenmap question on scanning

Tags: audit

Using Zenmap, I continue to get host down notifications when completing a scan on all ip addresses scanned, what am I doing wrong?  I am new to infosec and loving it so far..

Comment: Could you edit your equation to add the command and parameters that Zenmap is executing? This information can be found in a textbox in the Zenmap GUI.